# What is the opposite of generalization?

Tags: antonyms, terminology, generic-term

Via a quick check in the thesaurus, it returned the terms 'specific' and 'specificity'. What I have in mind is 'specificalization', but that word does not exist.

Comment: Although *specific* is an apt antonym for the sense of *general* from which the verb *to generalize* derives its meanings, the verb from *to specify* is not a particularly good antonym for most of the meanings of *to generalize*.  It would help if you clarified the sense of *generalization* that you want to oppose, and especially if you gave an example of how you want to use the word you're after.

Comment: *Specialization* seems like the obvious answer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some words that also come to my mind asides from specialization: example, exemplar, illustration, implementation. These are all synonymous, but *specialization* or *specification* are probably good fits.

Answer (score 3):

In logic, the opposite to generalization is instantiation.  When you have shown than something is true of an arbitrarily chosen individual, the rule of universal generalization allows you to infer that it is true of all individuals.  When you know that something is true of all individuals, universal instantiation allows you to infer that it is true of any arbitrarily chosen individual.

Answer (score 2):

**particularization**, but use with caution, it isn't very common in the wild.

> the act of particularizing :  the condition of being particularized

"Particularization." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 5 May 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned so far: "*get down to brass tacks*", "*get down to particulars*", *nitpick*...